# java.lang.StackOverflowError happens when connect to Neo4j, in Springboot Mybatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, mybatis

As the title suggests, I met the StackOverFlow problem when I connect to Neo4j in Springboot with Mybatis.
The CQL runs well in Neo4j desktop, but the api returns a 500 result with the same CQL in mapper.

The error message goes like:

```
2020-12-31 20:22:24.560 ERROR 31232 --- [nio-9090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalizePrefix(WinNTFileSystem.java:186) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:111) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.normalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:279) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:224) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FilePermission$1.run(FilePermission.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FilePermission.init(FilePermission.java:212) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.io.FilePermission.<init>(FilePermission.java:299) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getPermission(FileURLConnection.java:228) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getPermission(JarFileFactory.java:166) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.getCachedJarFile(JarFileFactory.java:136) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getInputStream(JarURLConnection.java:152) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:2223) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.<init>(DatabaseMetaData.java:100) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDatabaseMetaData.<init>(HttpDatabaseMetaData.java:34) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDatabaseMetaData.<init>(HttpDatabaseMetaData.java:43) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpConnection.getMetaData(HttpConnection.java:105) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpConnection.getMetaData(HttpConnection.java:40) ~[neo4j-jdbc-driver-3.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.getMetaData(ProxyConnection.java:380) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.getMetaData(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:256) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:261) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:261) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getNextResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:261) ~[mybatis-3.5.2.jar:3.5.2]
```

(The last line was repeated hundreds of times)

Here are my configurations and code:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.neo4j.dw</groupId>
    <artifactId>dw</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>amazonMovies</name>
    <description>Amazon Movies Data Warehouse</description>

    <!--    <properties>-->
    <!--        <java.version>1.8</java.version>-->
    <!--    </properties>-->

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!--        Neo4j-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mybatis-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- solve: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- fastjson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.47</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
            <version>1.46</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--分页插件 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.neo4j.dw.DwApplication</mainClass>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

mybatis_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDriver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:neo4j:http://localhost:7474"/>
                <property name="username" value="neo4j"/>
                <property name="password" value="ETL2020"/>
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="./mapper/*.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.neo4j.jdbc.http.HttpDriver
    url: jdbc:neo4j:http://localhost:7474
    username: neo4j
    password: ETL2020

mybatis-plus:
  mapper-locations: classpath*:/mapper/**Mapper.xml
  type-aliases-package: com.neo4j.dw.Model

server:
  port: 9090
```

TestController

```
package com.neo4j.dw.Controller;

import com.neo4j.dw.Model.User;
import com.neo4j.dw.Service.TestService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello(){
        return "hello";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return testService.selectUsers();
    }
}
```

TestServiceImpl

```
package com.neo4j.dw.Service.Impl;

import com.neo4j.dw.Mapper.TestMapper;
import com.neo4j.dw.Model.User;
import com.neo4j.dw.Service.TestService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {
    @Autowired
    private TestMapper testMapper;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<User> selectUsers(){
        return testMapper.selectUsers();
    }
}
```

TestMapper

```
package com.neo4j.dw.Mapper;

import com.neo4j.dw.Model.User;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Mapper
public interface TestMapper {

    ArrayList<User> selectUsers();
}
```

User

```
package com.neo4j.dw.Model;

import lombok.*;
import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.annotation.TableField;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class User {
    @TableField("userId")
    public String userId;

    @TableField("profileName")
    public String profileName;
}
```

TestMapper.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.neo4j.dw.Mapper.TestMapper">
    <select id="selectUsers" resultType="int">
        MATCH (n1)-[r]->(n2) RETURN count(*)
    </select>
</mapper>
```

I'm new in Neo4j and Mybatis.
Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this error?
Thanks a million!

Comment: The SO error is coming while the program tries to load a jar file from the classpath. The file path where the jar is present seems to be causing issue. You can try attaching a debugger and see what path it's causing this issue with.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried to debug and found that the URL was not correctly fetched when Springboot made the neo4j connection. Host, port, and Authorization are all empty value. Is there something wrong with my configuration? @Shailendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no MyBatis integration in:

- neither Spring Data Neo4j 5 (added via `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` in your POM, included up until Spring Boot 2.3)
- nor Neo4j OGM (which is the library Spring Data Neo4j 5 is built upon).

If you want to get started, you should probably get started with Spring Data Neo4j 6 (aka SDN 6), i.e. the latest version of Spring Data Neo4j at the time of writing. If you upgrade Spring Boot to the latest version (2.4 at the time of writing), you will automatically get it.

You should probably start with the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.x/reference/html/#reference) of SDN 6.
You also can find an example [here](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j).

As you will learn, you can get rid of MyBatis, SDN 6 (and 5 via Neo4j OGM) takes care of the mapping already.

Comment: Thank you so much! I learned a lot from your suggest!